# Неправильно работает метод с функцией(функция вне метода работает правильно)

Tags: javascript

функция сама по себе

```
function sumSalaries() {

    let sum = 0;
    for (let salary of Object.values(salaries)) {
      sum += salary;
    }
  
    console.log(sum) 
  }
sumSalaries()
```

Функция внутри метода объекта

```
salaries.sum2 = function () {

    let sum = 0;
    for (let salary of Object.values(salaries)) {
      sum += salary;
    }
  
    console.log(sum) 
  }
  salaries.sum2()
```

Сам объект

```
let salaries = {
  worker0: 5040,
  worker1: 6400,
  worker2: 3000,
  worker3: 2100,
  worker4: 1300,
  worker5: 600,
};
```

Нужно что бы выходила сумма всех ключей и это работает в функции, но когда я помещаю её в метод то всё ломается

[image]

- Первая строка-сама функция
- Вторая стока-функция в методе

Comment: как ты думаешь, что такое (чем является) `sum2` у объекта  `salaries`?

Comment: Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, выберите тот, который подошел вам больше всего для решения вашего вопроса и пометьте его галочкой "Принять".

Answer (score 1):

При простом добавлении свойства в объект, оно становится перечислимым, поэтому входит в набор возвращаемый такими функциями как `Object.values`, `Object.keys` и т.д.

Для решения достаточно добавить функцию не в объект, а в прототип. Свойства из прототипа не возвращаются указанными выше методами.

Для получения прототипа объекта можно использовать метод [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

```js
let salaries = {
  worker0: 5040,
  worker1: 6400,
  worker2: 3000,
  worker3: 2100,
  worker4: 1300,
  worker5: 600,
};

Object.getPrototypeOf(salaries).sum2 = function() {

  let sum = 0;
  for (let salary of Object.values(salaries)) {
    sum += salary;
  }

  console.log(sum)
}
salaries.sum2()
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо исключать себя(функцию sum2) из рассчета.

**this** - это контекст фукнции, в данном случае, это сам объект **salaries**.

```js
let salaries = {
  worker0: 5040,
  worker1: 6400,
  worker2: 3000,
  worker3: 2100,
  worker4: 1300,
  worker5: 600,
};

salaries.sum2 = function () {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i in this) {
    if (i !== 'sum2') {
      sum += this[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(salaries.sum2())
```

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно что бы выходила сумма всех ключей и это работает в функции, но когда я помещаю её в метод то всё ломается

Так ты пытаешься прибавить и саму функцию. Она ведь так же есть теперь в ключах. ;)

```js
let salaries = {
  worker0: 5040,
  worker1: 6400,
  worker2: 3000,
  worker3: 2100,
  worker4: 1300,
  worker5: 600,
};

salaries.sum2 = function() {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let salary of Object.values(this)) {
    if (typeof salary === 'number') sum += salary;
  }
  console.log(sum)
}
salaries.sum2()
```